# Is it possible to register document lifecycle in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, token, lifecycle

I want to create a function that creates token documents in elasticsearch and gives them token lifecycle just like in redis and deletes them automatically over time.

Does Elasticsearch support that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES 2.0 (looooong time ago), there used to be a [`_ttl` metadata field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-ttl-field.html) that served exactly this purpose.

That feature has been deprecated in favor of using an index per timeframe (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, etc) and [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) to manage the lifecycle of data.

You should be able to achieve what you want with proper time-based indices and an appropriate index lifecycle policy managing those indices.

Comment: Is it impossible to put a pipeline in the ilm policy so that expired documents can be deleted when the policy is executed periodically?
 *I use google translator, so the sentences may be weird.

Comment: Ingest pipeline do not provide a way to delete documents.