# how to add auto remove field in logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to add a _ttl field in logstash so that elasticsearch removes the document after  a while, 120 seconds in this case but that's for testing.

```
filter {
    if "drop" in [message] {
        drop { }
    }

    add_field => { "_ttl" => "120s" }
}
```

but now nothing is logged in elasticsearch.

I have 2 questions.
Where is logged what is going wrong, maybe the syntax of the filter is wrong?

How do I add a ttl field to elasticsearch for auto removal?

Comment: The `_ttl` field has been deprecated in version 2. See this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71464487/4604579 (hint: use ILM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a filter to logstash.conf with a mutator it works:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "_ttl" => "120s" }
    }
}

POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**Results:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "myindex",
      ...................
      "_ttl": "120s",
```

For the other question, cant really help there. Im running logstash as container so logging is read with:

```
docker logs d492eb3c3d0d
```